# Estimating the variation of the scaling factor from a transformation onto a theoretical graph

Tags: bootstrap, error, residuals, scale-estimator

I have a numerically calculated graph, on unit-less coordinates.

I have experimental data which corresponds to a point on that graph.

The data has units, and to make it unitless one has to divide it by a "constant" which determines where these points end up on the graph, I call this "constant" the scaling factor.

To find the corresponding point on the graph, the scaling factor needs to be found.

To find the scaling factor, I minimize the sum of square distances of the data from the graph (the graph is invariant to this scaling, since it's already in the unit-less coordinates).

How should I estimate the variation for the estimated scale factor from such a fit?

Is bootstrapping the correct way to go, or is there anything smarter to do?

Is there any sense in doing residual analysis?

Edit:

[image: scaling cloud of points to find their corresponding point on the graph]

Here, the point of clouds with an arbitrary scaling coefficient is depicted in red.

The green cloud is the cloud after the scaling transformation using the scaling factor which minimizes the sum of squares deviation of the data from the graph.

Comment: I can't follow your situation. Can you make this more concrete? Can you provide an example &/or some sample data?

Comment: @gung I've added an image with a description, hope it makes it more tangible.

Comment: You're talking about scale on unit-less coordinates. That makes no sense...

Comment: @AlexR. the data points have units, the graph does not. to plot the points on this graph, you have to divide the data points by a number with units which cancel the units of the data, but the size of that number determines where these points end up on the graph.

Comment: @AlexR. thanks, for the feedback, I've edited the question to better explain this part.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I still don't understand how "error" is defined here, or for that matter what you would be bootstrapping

Comment: @ssdecontrol By error I mean to give an idea of the distribution of scaling factors which agree with the measurements.  

Bootstrapping is done by composing many randomly selected subsets of the measurement data and getting the scaling factor for each subset, thus getting a distribution of possible scaling factors which agree with most of the data.

Comment: "variation" would be a more appropriate word than "error" in that case. What kind of residual analysis did you have in mind? I don't see any residuals here.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yeah, I was saying error, since I use it to show error margins... But if you think it'd make it clearer I can fix it. BTW, I've edited the previous comment while you were typing this one regarding bootstrapping, in case you have missed it.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "error margin" if there's no "error". It's just a visualization of a distribution -- very important, but _not_ an error.

Comment: I was wondering about the "residual analysis" you refer to in the main question

Comment: @ssdecontrol Well, regarding the "error", if the actual value does not vary, but only my estimation of it (i.e. in an ideal world the distribution would be a delta function) the variation can be thought of as an error, can it not? But in this instance, I can't be sure how much of the variation is due to measurement noise and how much is due to actual variation in the sample... So distribution is more accurate here anyway.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Regarding the residual analysis - some of my colleagues argued that bootstrapping artificially over samples the data, and a preferred way to estimate the variation of the data is to examine the distribution of the distance of the cloud around the point it belongs to on the graph... It makes no sense to me, since it doesn't refer to the distribution of the scaling factor... And I want to show how sure I am of that scaling factor.

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe you are right that it makes no sense. That "residual analysis" addresses an entirely different problem.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Thanks, So do you think what I'm currently doing with bootstrapping is the way to go? I don't know of any alternative that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the comments, there's no "residual analysis" to be done here.

There is one potential issue with bootstrapping. Each draw is supposed to simulate a different run of your experiment, such that a large number of draws approximates the "population" of possible experiment outcomes. Therefore, in order for the bootstrap procedure to work here, you must be able to justify the claim that all possible experimental outcomes are represented in your data.

For example, let's say there's a bowl of 100 red and blue jelly beans on the table, and you'd like to estimate the proportion of red ones. In truth, there are 50 of each color. You blindly draw a sample of 15 jelly beans, of which 3 are red and the rest are blue. No matter how many bootstrap replicates of this 15-bean sample you take, you will never be able to accurately estimate the true proportion of red jelly beans in the bowl. Your estimates will always converge incorrectly to $3/15$ instead of $50/100$. This might have been what your colleagues were referring to when they said the bootstrap "artificially over samples the data."

Put another way: the bootstrap is only valid when your sample is a reasonable approximation of its population. It's up to you to make that determination.